# Airflow webserver doesn't find scheduler in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I'm currently trying to run a minimal Airflow ennvironment to test a few DAGs on my local machine. The setup is quite basic: I am using `docker-compose` to spin an Airflow webserver and a scheduler after initialising the local sqlite db.

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like the following:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  webserver:
    image: apache/airflow
    container_name: airflow_webserver
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      AIRFLOW_RUNAS_WEBSERVER: 1
    depends_on: 
      - scheduler
    entrypoint:  /scripts/wait-for-it.sh scheduler:8793 -t 40 -- /scripts/docker-entrypoint.sh

  scheduler:
    image: apache/airflow
    container_name: airflow_scheduler
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8793:8793
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
      - ./scripts:/scripts
    environment: 
      AIRFLOW_RUNAS_SCHEDULER: 1
    entrypoint: /scripts/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Where my `docker-entrypoint.sh` is like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

AIRFLOW_USERNAME=test
AIRFLOW_PASSWORD=test

if [ "$AIRFLOW_RUNAS_SCHEDULER" = "1" ]; then
    echo "initializing airflow database"
    airflow db init
    echo "running airflow scheduler"
    while true
    do
        airflow scheduler
        echo "restarting airflow scheduler"
        sleep 1
    done
elif [ "$AIRFLOW_RUNAS_WEBSERVER" = "1" ]; then
    echo "running airflow webserver"
    airflow db upgrade
    airflow users create \
        --username=$AIRFLOW_USERNAME \
        --password=$AIRFLOW_PASSWORD \
        --firstname=test \
        --lastname=test \
        --email=test@test.com \
        --role=Admin
    exec airflow webserver -p 8080
elif [ "$AIRFLOW_RUNAS_WORKER" = "1" ]; then
    echo "running airflow worker"
    exec airflow worker
elif [ "$AIRFLOW_RUNAS_FLOWER" = "1" ]; then
    echo "running airflow flower"
    exec airflow flower
else
    echo "ERROR: no AIRFLOW_RUNAS_* variable set"
    exit 1
fi
```

Now, from the logs I can clearly see that running `docker-compose up` both `airflow webserver` and `airflow scheduler` spin up their services correctly even though it seems Airflow webserver is having an hard time finding the scheduler. On the UI I am greeted with a warm:

> The scheduler does not appear to be running.
> The DAGs list may not update, and new tasks will not be scheduled.

How should I go at finding out why the two services don't talk to each other?

#### Update:

Strangely enough everything works well if I adapt my `docker-entrypoint.sh` to run all the steps within the same service with a trivial

```sh
exec airflow webserver -p 8080 & exec airflow scheduler
```

This makes following complicated as everything gets logged by the same container.

Comment: Same issue here @anddt.
Solution is the same. Problem, we won't be able to run 1 webserver container and 2 or several schedulers containers and then take profit of the HA scheduler in airflow 2. Furthermore some of the developers of Airflow says that overriding entrypoint is not a good practice :S:

Did u achieve something else?